# eclipse cdt - how to set the active build configuration from the command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-cdt, buildconfiguration

In eclipse CDT from the command line I can create workspaces, import and build projects, etc. This works.

I'm trying to change the 'active configuration' of a project from (X) to (Y) 
In the GUI, I can do this:  Right click on the project name, go down to "Build Configurations" -> "Set Active"

I want to do this from the command line, I'm no java developer otherwise I would set a breakpoint and step through the java code and figure this out {I don't have a java build environment setup either, simply to complex for my needs right now}

Option 1 - the setting is stored in a file.

Somewhere - in a saved file - Eclipse has to have some setting that marks a project as "the active configuration" but I can't seem to find this.

Option 2 - something from the command line ... that will let me do this

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you import and build projects from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for option 2, until I realized there is a fast way to set the active configuration for all of my projects.

I just need to select all of my projects, then:

> Build Configuration > Set Ative > My_Config

Answer (score 1):

For Option 2, you can select which configuration to use while building from the command line with this

```
eclipse -nosplash -data . -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -build <project name>/<configuration>
```

See this bug report for more details: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281397

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer for Option 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180036/where-does-eclipse-store-active-configuration-info-of-a-cdt-project/43198012#43198012)

> It is stored in /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects//.indexes/properties.index, in a binary format.

I'm also looking for answer for Option 2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)