# Where does eclipse store Active configuration info of a CDT project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

All the configuration information about debug and release modes are stored in .cproject file. But I don't find any information about which is the Active configuration in .project or .cproject file. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stored in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/<project>/.indexes/properties.index`, in a binary format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how we can change active configuration of a project through command line?

Comment: @Sree I don't know if there's a built-in way to do that; there may not be. If there isn't, you could write an Eclipse plugin that changes the active configuration. You could then interact with that plugin from the command-line in various ways. For example, you could invoke an instance of Eclipse with that plugin loaded via the command-line. Or, you could launch a command-line application that communicates with the plugin over IPC. Or the command-line application could write instructions to a file, which the plugin checks upon startup.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @HighCommander4. much appreciated!